# Not able to extract sdkmanager to install api "android 25"

Tags: java, appium-android

I am trying to install Andriod api via sdkmanager with the command

```
*sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-25"*
```

but facing below error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
>           at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.(SchemaModule.java:156)
>           at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.(SchemaModule.java:75)
>           at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
>           at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
>           at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
>           at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
>           at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
>           ... 5 more

My java version is

> java version "1.8.0_231"

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am able to run the above command below are the steps

First open sdkmanager.bat with any text editor
Then find this line

```
  %JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %SDKMANAGER_OPTS%
```

And change it to this line

```
  %JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% --add-modules java.xml.bind %JAVA_OPTS% %SDKMANAGER_OPTS%
```

This worked for me